# Group by multi-index without losing an index with pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I currently have a dataset with two indexes, year and zip code, but multiple observations (prices) per zip code. How can I get the average price per zip code, so that I only have distinct observations per zip code and year.

[Screenshot of current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N76Me.png)

Comment: Use `df.groupby(level=[0,1]).mean()`

Comment: @max0506, that isn't an error message. Take a look at Python repr https://dbader.org/blog/python-repr-vs-str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) with level parameter:

```
df = s.mean(level=[0,1])
```

**Sample**:

```
s = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[5,5,4,5,5,4],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
}).set_index(['F','B'])['E']
print (s)
F  B
a  5    5
   5    3
   4    6
b  5    9
   5    2
   4    4
Name: E, dtype: int64

df = s.mean(level=[0,1]).reset_index()
print (df)
   F  B    E
0  a  5  4.0
1  a  4  6.0
2  b  5  5.5
3  b  4  4.0
```

Comment: Great, that works!

Do you also know how I can count the values I have per zip code and year before I take an average to create an extra column with the number of observations next to the average price? Thanks!

Comment: @max0506 - what is your code for output in question?

Comment: Perhaps something like this, but it's not working since zip is an index and I want to have it per zip code and year: df = pd.DataFrame(df_raw['sale_price'])
df["sales_per_zip"] = df['zip'].value_counts()
df = df.mean(level=[0,1])

Comment: @max0506 - Use `df = s.groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(['mean','size'])`